# what's view of tabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios

My app has a `TabBarController` and `ViewController`, in the `ViewController` has a `TableView`, when I select one cell of `TableView`, will display other `ViewController` without `TabBarController` and view will resize to bottom of screen.
When I debug in the `ViewController`

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.tabBarController.view.subviews);
NSLog(@"%@", self.view.subviews);
```

I saw

```
2013-10-04 17:36:08.805 Btalk[6256:c07] (  
"<UITransitionView: 0x7d468a0; frame = (0 0; 320 431); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d46950>>",
"<UITabBar: 0x7a691b0; frame = (0 431; 320 49); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a692a0>>"
)

2013-10-04 17:36:10.737 Btalk[6256:c07] (
"<UITableView: 0x8b7ba00; frame = (0 0; 320 423); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7aadcd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7aaee30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>",
"<UIView: 0x7abfed0; frame = (0 423; 320 37); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7abff30>>"
)
```

Any one can explain for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably declared the `UITabBarController` in your `UIViewController`. That way, that view controller is the only one who has a tabbarcontroller. Declare the tabbarcontroller in the App Delegate like this and it'll be fine:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstViewController, secondViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If you're trying to accomplish what iOS has in for example the music app you have to add a `UINavigationController`. That works like this:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```